# How to simplify a square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can the following:

$$
\sqrt{27-10\sqrt{2}}
$$

Be simplified to:

$$
5 - \sqrt{2}
$$

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strategies to denest  nested radicals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/196155/strategies-to-denest-nested-radicals)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're faced with a question that says "Prove that $\sqrt{27-10\sqrt{2}}$ $=5 - \sqrt{2}$", then it's just a matter of squaring $5 - \sqrt{2}$ and seeing that you get $27-10\sqrt{2}$.  But suppose the question your faced with is to find a square root of $27-10\sqrt{2}$ of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$, where $a$ and $b$ are rational.  Then you have
$$
27-10\sqrt{2}=\left(a+b\sqrt{2}\right)^2 = a^2 + 2ab\sqrt{2} + 2b^2
$$
so
\begin{align}
27 & = a^2+2b^2 \\[8pt]
-10 & = 2ab
\end{align}
From the second equation we get $a=-5/b$, then the first equation becomes
$$
27 = \frac{25}{b^2} + 2b^2
$$
or
$$
2(b^2)^2 -27b^2 + 25 = 0.
$$
A solution is $b^2=1$, and you can go on from there to find $b$ and then $a$.

(And remember that the number will have *two* square roots.)

**Later note:** In order for all this to work, we have to rely on the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.  That enables us to conclude that the rational parts are equal and the irrational parts are equal, so we have two equations.

Comment: It might be worth to mention that $5-\sqrt 2>0$.

Answer (score 8):

No lucky guesses are needed, there is a [simple denesting algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/220879/23500) for $\rm\:\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{n}}$

---

**Simple Denesting Rule** $\rm\ \ \ \color{#0A0}{subtract\ out}\ \sqrt{norm}\:,\ \ then\ \  \color{brown}{divide\ out}\ \sqrt{trace} $

$\begin{array}{lll}\rm Recall\ \ \  w = a + b\sqrt{n}\ \ \ has\!\!\! &{\bf norm} &\!\!\!\rm=\: w\:\cdot\: w' = &\!\!\!\!\rm(a + b\sqrt{n})\ \cdot\: (a - b\sqrt{n})\ =\: a^2 - n\: b^2 \\ \\  
\rm and,\ furthermore,\ \  w\ \ has \!\!\!&{\bf trace} &\!\!\!\!\rm =\: w+w' =  &\!\!\!\!\rm (a + b\sqrt{n}) + (a - b\sqrt{n})\: =\:  2\:a\end{array}$

---

Here $\:27-10\sqrt{2}\:$ has norm $= 23^2.\,$ $\rm\, \color{#0A0}{Subtracting\ out}\ \sqrt{norm}\ = -23\ $ yields $\  50-10\sqrt{2}\:$

and this has $\rm\ \sqrt{trace}\: =\: 10,\ \ hence\ \  \ \color{brown}{dividing\ it\ out}\ $ of this yields $\rm\ 5 - \sqrt{2} =\:$ sought sqrt.

---

**Remark** $\ $ The sign of the norm sqrt was chosen to make the trace sqrt rational. The same answer would arise using the opposite sign, but with slightly more work (rationalizing a denominator). $\ $ For many further examples see [other posts on radical denesting.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+denesting+subtract+norm+trace)

Comment: Nice technique and a good example of why there are really two solutions when taking the square root, contrary to what most mathematicians would like it to be (a single-valued function), and that it doesn't matter much whether you take the square root of an unknown or a "simple number".

Comment: Where does these names come from? ("norm" and "trace") I see that the first one is similar to calculating the norm of a complex number, but there's no $i$ in it, so why does it still work similarly to complex conjugates? And why is the norm *subtracted* instead of divided out? Why is it the trace which is divided out instead? The trick is really nice, but it would be nicer if you explained *why* does this magic work so well.

Comment: Oh, and one thing you wrote is a bit misleading: You put this in a way suggesting that one has to divide by the trace of the original square-rooted number ($w$), but when I tried this, it didn't work. One has to divide out by the trace of the partial answer obtained along the way instead, which is *not* the original $w$, but $w - \sqrt{norm}$.

Comment: Even if you link to the source, I think it's bad practice to just copy and paste someone else's answer...

Answer (score 6):

Note that $27=5^2+\sqrt2^2$ and $10\sqrt2=2\times5\times\sqrt2$

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $$\begin{align}27-10\sqrt{2} & = 25 - 2\cdot 5\sqrt{2} + 2 \\
& = 5^2 - 2\cdot5\sqrt2 + \left(\sqrt2\right)^2\\
& = \left(5 - \sqrt 2\right)^2
\end{align} $$

I don't know any way to notice this except to just get lucky and notice it; I didn't realize it could happen until sometime in high school when I was astounded to discover that $\sqrt{7+4\sqrt3} = 2+\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Compare the squares of both expressions.

Answer (score 5):

Set the nested radical as the difference of two square roots so that $$\sqrt{27-10\sqrt{2}}=(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})$$ Then square both sides so that $$27-10\sqrt{2}=a-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}+b$$ Set (1) $$a+b=27$$ and set (2) $$-2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=-10\sqrt{2}$$   Square both sides of (2) to get $$4ab= 200$$ and solve for $b$ to get $$b=\frac{50}{a}$$ Replacing $b$ in (1) gives $$a+\frac{50}{a}=27$$ Multiply all terms by $a$ and convert to the quadratic equation $$a^2-27a+50=0$$ Solving the quadratic gives $a=25$ or $a=2$. Replacing $a$ and $b$ in the first difference of square roots formula above with $25$ and $2$ the solutions to the quadratic we have $$\sqrt{25}-\sqrt{2}$$ or $$5-\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: What if the solutions to the quadratic were also irrational, so that $a$ and $b$ become nested inside their radicals again? Or is this possibility somehow excluded?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{27 - 10\sqrt{2}}$$
$$= \sqrt{25 + 2 - 2.5.\sqrt{2}}$$
$$= \sqrt{5^{2} - 2.5.\sqrt{2} +{\sqrt{2}}^2}$$
$$= \sqrt{{(5 - \sqrt{2})}^2}$$

$$= (5 - \sqrt{2})$$
$$= R.H.S$$

Comment: You need equals signs rather than arrows.  I would have written something similar as $$\sqrt{27-10\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{27-2\sqrt{ 25 \times 2}} = \sqrt{25-2\sqrt{ 25 }\sqrt{2} +2} = \sqrt{(\sqrt{25} - \sqrt{2})^2}$$

Comment: @Henry: Thanks corrected. Its been ages I am solving some math problem

Comment: But then you have to "guess" how to split that $27$.