# How to factorize this $\sqrt{8 - 2\sqrt{7}}$?

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

When I was at high school, our teacher showed us a technique to simplify square 
roots like this  $\sqrt{8 - 2\sqrt{7}}$ that I forgot.
It was something like 8 = 7+1; 7 = 7*1; and using them we could represent $\sqrt{8 - 2\sqrt{7}}$ in simpler form. I would be happy if you can show how it works, and how this technique is called.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757917, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214527

Comment: Sorry but I forgot its name. So I didn't know how to search.

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

$$
8=1^2+(\sqrt{7})^2
$$

and $(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt { 8-2\sqrt { 7 }  } =\sqrt { { \left( \sqrt { 7 }  \right)  }^{ 2 }-2\sqrt { 7 } +1 } =\sqrt { { \left( \sqrt { 7 } -1 \right)  }^{ 2 } } =\sqrt { 7 } -1$$

Answer (score 3):

Maybe that the formula that you do not remember is:
$$
\sqrt{a\pm \sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{a+ \sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{a- \sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}
$$
that can easily verified ( see my answer to the similar question: [Denesting a square root: $\sqrt{7 + \sqrt{14}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214527/denesting-a-square-root-sqrt7-sqrt14/1454914#1454914)) and works well when $a^2-b$ is a perfect square.

In this case we have:
$$\sqrt{8 - 2\sqrt{7}}=\sqrt{8 - \sqrt{28}} \quad \Rightarrow \quad a^2-b=36$$

and, using the formula:
$$
\sqrt{8 - 2\sqrt{7}}=\sqrt{7}-1
$$

Answer (score 2):

Try making perfect square inside of that square root, as you can see that $$2\sqrt{7}=2\times1\times\sqrt{7}$$ and $$8=1+(\sqrt{7})^2$$ Then apply $$a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Such square roots can  be *mechanically* computed by a [Simple Denesting Rule:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816527/242)

Here $\ 8-2\sqrt 7\ $ has norm $= 36.\:$ $\rm\ \color{blue}{Subtracting\ out}\,\ \sqrt{norm}\ = 6\,\ $ yields $\,\  2-2\sqrt 7\:$

which has $\, {\rm\ \sqrt{trace}}\, =\, \sqrt{4}\, =\, 2.\,\ \ \ \rm \color{brown}{Dividing\ it\ out}\,\ $ of the above  yields $\ \ \ 1-\sqrt 7$

Negate it to get the positive root.  Many more worked examples are in [prior posts on this rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+denesting+subtract+norm+trace)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:$$\sqrt{X\pm Y}=\sqrt{\dfrac {X+\sqrt{X^2-Y^2}}2}\pm\sqrt{\dfrac {X-\sqrt{X^2-Y^2}}2}\tag1$$
For $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X>Y$. Therefore, we have $x=8,\ Y=\sqrt{28}$ so$$\sqrt{8-2\sqrt7}=\sqrt{\dfrac {8+\sqrt{64-28}}2}-\sqrt{\dfrac {8-\sqrt{64-28}}2}=\sqrt7-1\tag2$$